# shared_ptr to an array

Tags: c++, c++11

How can you dynamically allocate "n number of elements" to which a shared_ptr will point to?

I was able to create a static array that a shared pointer will point to, but I'd like the user to enter a number and then allocate n number of elements.

```
shared_ptr<int[10]> p = make_shared<int[10]>();
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` ?

Comment: No you can't do that, an array with different length has different type

Comment: "I was able to create a static array that a shared pointer will point to" - you had better not do this - if you do, you are in Undefined Behaviour Land.

Comment: Consider using `std::array<int, 10>` instead of `int[10]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should create that `shared_ptr` like that

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>() );
```

You must give other deleter to `shared_ptr`

You can't use `std::make_shared`, because that function gives only 1 parameter, for create pointer on array you must create deleter too.

Or you can use too (like in comments , with array or with vector, which has own deleter)

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<int,6>> ptr(std::make_shared<std::array<int, 6>>(std::array<int, 6>()));
```

How get particular element?
Like that

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());
sp.get()[0] = 5;
std::cout << sp.get()[0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

The language currently lacks the ability to use `make_shared` to accomplish that. It is addressed in [P0674](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0674r0.html). Pretty sure it's going to make its way into the language, though it won't be C++11.

The wording will allow you to say

```
auto p = std::make_shared<int[10]>()
```

or

```
auto p = std::make_shared<int[]>(10)
```

Until C++20 (or whenever the proposal gets officially standardized), you're stuck with using the `new` syntax as linked in [21koizyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950534/27678).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think better for this problem is unique_ptr template.

```
int amount = 10;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> name(new int[amount]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the form below is wrong.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<int,6>> ptr(std::make_shared<std::array<int, 6>>(std::array<int, 6>()));
```

It invokes two times destructor.

If your input is not native type such as int, it will lead to a crash.

One can try it.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<int,6>> ptr(std::make_shared<std::array<int, 6>>());
```

Maybe the claim above is correct?

Is there anyone know why it invokes two times of destructor?

any thoughts?

Comment: While that certainly takes over the make_shared function unable to be used for arrays, it certainly doesn't help with the question where the user should be allowed to decide how many elements he wants the array to have. Hence the constructor workaround being used as the best one until C++20,